# Bigquery Union results in ambiguous schema when mixing window functions with repeated values

Tags: sql, nested, google-bigquery, window-functions, union-all

I'm creating a query which mixes window functions with repeated values in a union and I'm getting an "Union results in ambiguous schema" error. 
I've been able to reproduce the issue with a public dataset:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    ngram,
    cell.value,
    SUM(1) OVER (ORDER BY ngram)
  FROM
    [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams]
  LIMIT
    1000),
  (
  SELECT
    ngram,
    cell.value
  FROM
    [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams]
  LIMIT
    1000)
```

I'm aware that flattering will serve as workaround for the issue but the query is part of a bigger query where the number of rows is counted. With flatten I'll end up with more rows than what I'd like in an intermediate query.

The second workaround is to use window functions in all the subqueries but that is really dirty as I'll be requiring extra resources that are not really required. like :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    ngram,
    cell.value,
    SUM(1) OVER (ORDER BY ngram) as summatory
  FROM
    [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams]
  LIMIT
    100),
  (
  SELECT
    ngram,
    cell.value
    ,sum(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ngram) as summatory
  FROM
    [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams]
  LIMIT
    100)
```

I hope that I can solve the issue without having to migrate all the query to Standard SQL.

Comment: what is `flattering`? Also I dont see any `UNION` there

Comment: Can you clarify why you do not want to use standard SQL? It doesn't have this kind of problem with unions.

Comment: Hi Juan Carlos, I meant the FLATTEN clause of BIGQUERY Legacy SQL. The "," IN BIGQUERY means a UNION ALL.

Comment: Hi Elliott, there are two main reasons I don't want to apply Standard SQL here. The first is that our sofware uses a dynamic sql builder wich creates variations of the query depending on the selected parameters. It means that we cannot create a new query to solve this issue but we have to change the query we are using for all the different scenarios. the second is that dealing with repeated fields in Standard SQL doesn't look as simple as it is with Legacy SQL.

Comment: There is actually a third rason. We use subquries with different number of columns depending on the source. With Legacy SQL, it simply works, but with Standar SQL we should control the positions of the columns at every subquery in the union.

Comment: it is hard to give any specific suggestion without understanding what it is that you are trying to do then with that query within a bigger query. you might want to provide more insight on this